# Class not found al ejecutar php artisan migrate

Tags: eloquent, laravel-7

Estoy realizando tres tablas: una de *productos*, otra de *modelos_productos* y una tercera de *marcas_productos*. Las relaciones entre sí son las siguientes:

Estas líneas son parte de mi *create_products_table*: donde establezco la relacion con los id de las tablas de marcas y modelos.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
                $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('marcas_productos');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('model_id');
                $table->foreign('model_id')->references('id')->on('modelos_productos');
```

Y esta otra es la relacion de mi *create_modelos_productos_table*, donde la relaciono con la tabla de marcas mediante su id.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
$table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('marcas_productos');
```

Por otro lado utilicé las relaciones de eloquent en los modelos.

Este es el modelo de *marcaProducto*:

```
class modeloProducto extends Model
{
    public function marca(){
        return $this->belongsTo(marcaProducto::class);
    }

    public function producto(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Este es el modelo de marcaProducto:

```
class marcaProducto extends Model
{
    public function modelo(){
        return $this->hasMany(modeloProducto::class);
    }

    public function producto(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class);
    }
}
```

y por último el Product

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id','id'); 
    }


    public function ptype(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Ptype::class,'ptype_id','id'); 
    }

    public function marca(){
        return $this->belongsTo(marcaProducto::class); 
    }
}
```

Al hacer `php artisan migrate` o `migrate:refresh obtengo` el siguiente error, el cual dice que esa clase no existe pero no logro entender el porqué.

```
 Class 'CreateModelosProductosTable' not found

at C:\Users\Mateo\OneDrive\Desktop\AXIS\globaltec-vuepanel-master\globaltec-vuepanel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php:453
    449|     public function resolve($file)
    450|     {
    451|         $class = Str::studly(implode('_', array_slice(explode('_', $file), 4)));
    452|
  > 453|         return new $class;
    454|     }
    455|

C:\Users\Mateo\OneDrive\Desktop\AXIS\globaltec-vuepanel-master\globaltec-vuepanel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php:189
      Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::resolve("2021_08_12_175659_create_modelos_productos_table")
```

Cabe destacar que mis migraciones las acomodé en el siguiente orden debido a las foreign keys. La primera migración es la de *marcas*, después *modelos* y por último *productos*.

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar el mensaje de error completo?, ¿te indica en qué archivo se origina dicho fallo?

Comment: @BetaM ahi edite y agregue el error completo

Comment: No se como creaste la clase para dicha migración, pero sugiero revises que nombre le diste tanto a la clase como al archivo, identificando la correcta aplicación de mayúsculas y minúsculas